# NSDictionary contain <nil> value while reading from plist file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am currently trying to read a plist file and trying to show the data in UITableView but while reading the plist file i am getting nil data.

**Edit**

Plist file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Mr</string>
        <key>First Name</key>
        <string>xxxxxx</string>
        <key>Last Name</key>
        <string>yyyyyyy</string>
        <key>Designation</key>
        <string>Senior Engineer</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Now in code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSArray *valueArray = [dict allKeys];

/*
Printing description of path:
/Users/rock/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/2567D2B3-56D4-4464-9EFC-CAB923ABE955/PlistTableView.app/Data.plist
Printing description of dict:
<nil>
Printing description of valueArray:
<nil>
*/
```

Now both dictionary & array contains no data what is the reason for this ? How can i show both key & value in table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plist file contains a dictionary *inside* an array. So either use

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

or change the structure of the plist file to

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>Mr</string>
    <key>First Name</key>
    <string>xxxxxx</string>
    <key>Last Name</key>
    <string>yyyyyyy</string>
    <key>Designation</key>
    <string>Senior Engineer</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: [array objectAtIndex:0];just returns the first dictionary value But if my array contains more than one dictionary then how can get all values?

Answer (score 1):

On the top you have an `<array>` and not `<dict>`. So it should go like this...

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *dict=[array objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *valueArray = [dict allKeys];
```

Comment: [array objectAtIndex:0];just returns the first dictionary value But if my array contains more than one dictionary then how can get all values?

Answer (score -1):

Try this at the beginning of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
```